# How eliminate the tab space in the column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an column with email in table `customer` where the data in the column contains special character: TAB

When I do a select, I need to remove the TAB space from that column.

Means there is an empty TAB space followed by the **EmailID:     xyz.com**

I tried using the `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` but that does not work here.

Comment: You could create a Sql function as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211346/how-to-remove-white-space-characters-from-a-string-in-sql-server

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Try this code

```
SELECT REPLACE([Column], char(9), '') From [dbo.Table]
```

char(9) is the TAB character

Comment: @tofutim why should it?

Comment: @roaima because '\t' is the actual representation of a `tab` character?

Comment: @EricWu in some contexts, certainly. In SQL generally? I doubt it, but I suppose it's possible. In SQL Server? Nope; see `select '\t'`

Answer (score 17):

```
UPDATE Table SET Column = REPLACE(Column, char(9), '')
```

Answer (score 16):

Use the Below Code for that

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Column1 = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Column1, CHAR(9), ''), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), '')))`
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting with SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and later, you can specify which characters to remove from both ends using `TRIM`.

To TRIM just TAB characters:

```
SELECT TRIM(CHAR(9) FROM Email)
FROM MyTable
```

To TRIM both TAB and SPACE characters:

```
SELECT TRIM(CONCAT(CHAR(9), CHAR(32)) FROM Email)
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: this helped very much when I needed to trim a tab off of the end of the string but not out of the middle

Answer (score -4):

See it might be worked -------

`UPDATE table_name SET  column_name=replace(column_name, ' ', '') //Remove white space`

`UPDATE table_name SET  column_name=replace(column_name, '\n', '') //Remove newline`

`UPDATE table_name SET  column_name=replace(column_name, '\t', '') //Remove all tab`

Thanks
Subroto