# How to remove white space characters from a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to remove white spaces from a string in SQL but `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` functions don't seem to work?

Column:

```
[ProductAlternateKey] [nvarchar](25) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS NULL
```

Query:

```
select REPLACE(ProductAlternateKey, ' ', '@'),
       LEN(ProductAlternateKey),
       LTRIM(RTRIM(ProductAlternateKey))      AS LRTrim,
       LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(ProductAlternateKey))) AS LRLen,
       ASCII(RIGHT(ProductAlternateKey, 1))   AS ASCIIR,
       ASCII(LEFT(ProductAlternateKey, 1))    AS ASCIIL,
       ProductAlternateKey
from DimProducts
where ProductAlternateKey  like '46783815%'
```

Result:

```
|  COLUMN_0 | COLUMN_1 | LRTrim | LRLen | ASCIIR | ASCIIL | PRODUCTALTERNATEKEY |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  46783815 |        8 | 46783815|     8|   53   |   52   |            46783815 |
| 46783815  |        10|46783815  |   10|   10   |   52   |           46783815  |
```

Can it be other symbols if `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` are not working, like "Enter"?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Using `ASCII(RIGHT(ProductAlternateKey, 1))` you can see that the right most character in row 2 is a Line Feed or Ascii Character 10.

This **can not** be removed using the standard `LTrim` `RTrim` functions.

You could however use `(REPLACE(ProductAlternateKey, CHAR(10), '')`

You may also want to account for carriage returns and tabs. These three (Line feeds, carriage returns and tabs) are the usual culprits and can be removed with the following :

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ProductAlternateKey, CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), '')))
```

If you encounter any more "white space" characters that can't be removed with the above then try one or all of the below:

```
--NULL
Replace([YourString],CHAR(0),'');
--Horizontal Tab
Replace([YourString],CHAR(9),'');
--Line Feed
Replace([YourString],CHAR(10),'');
--Vertical Tab
Replace([YourString],CHAR(11),'');
--Form Feed
Replace([YourString],CHAR(12),'');
--Carriage Return
Replace([YourString],CHAR(13),'');
--Column Break
Replace([YourString],CHAR(14),'');
--Non-breaking space
Replace([YourString],CHAR(160),'');
```

This list of potential white space characters could be used to create a function such as :

```
Create Function [dbo].[CleanAndTrimString] 
(@MyString as varchar(Max))
Returns varchar(Max)
As
Begin
    --NULL
    Set @MyString = Replace(@MyString,CHAR(0),'');
    --Horizontal Tab
    Set @MyString = Replace(@MyString,CHAR(9),'');
    --Line Feed
    Set @MyString = Replace(@MyString,CHAR(10),'');
    --Vertical Tab
    Set @MyString = Replace(@MyString,CHAR(11),'');
    --Form Feed
    Set @MyString = Replace(@MyString,CHAR(12),'');
    --Carriage Return
    Set @MyString = Replace(@MyString,CHAR(13),'');
    --Column Break
    Set @MyString = Replace(@MyString,CHAR(14),'');
    --Non-breaking space
    Set @MyString = Replace(@MyString,CHAR(160),'');

    Set @MyString = LTRIM(RTRIM(@MyString));
    Return @MyString
End
Go
```

Which you could then use as follows:

```
Select 
    dbo.CleanAndTrimString(ProductAlternateKey) As ProductAlternateKey
from DimProducts
```

Comment: You solution is working, because returning `46783815@@`, this gonna work always? no matter how many ASCII characters are in string?

Comment: It takes into account the usual culprits, so yes you should be OK with this.

Comment: I have a data at this link and it's not working , please have a look: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100826/data-is-splitting-into-multiple-rows-while-copying-from-sql-server-2012-to-excel?noredirect=1#comment46439769_29100826

Comment: Really late to this answer, but it is fantastic.  I had a bunch of blank little squares at the end of each value in a column value and it turned out to be ASCII code 8, which is a backspace?  Who knew!

Answer (score 4):

In that case, it isn't space that is in prefix/suffix.
The 1st row looks OK. Do the following for the contents of 2nd row.

```
ASCII(RIGHT(ProductAlternateKey, 1))
```

and

```
ASCII(LEFT(ProductAlternateKey, 1))
```

Comment: @shahkalpesh - thanks for this, didn't know about the ASCII function!

Answer (score 4):

There may be 2 spaces after the text, please confirm. You can use `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` functions also right?

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(ProductAlternateKey))
```

Maybe the extra space isn't ordinary spaces (ASCII 32, soft space)?
Maybe they are "hard space", ASCII 160?

```
ltrim(rtrim(replace(ProductAlternateKey, char(160), char(32))))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
CASE WHEN ProductAlternateKey is NOT NULL THEN
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25), LTRIM(RTRIM(ProductAlternateKey))) 
FROM DimProducts
where ProductAlternateKey  like '46783815%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the invisible character -

```
ALT+255
```

Try this

```
select REPLACE(ProductAlternateKey, ' ', '@')
--type ALT+255 instead of space for the second expression in REPLACE 
from DimProducts
where ProductAlternateKey  like '46783815%'
```

Raj

Edit: Based on ASCII() results, try `ALT+10` - use numeric keypad

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old post, but for the sake of others, by default, **TRIM only trims standard spaces, but you can readily override that.** It's pretty readable (and if you don't want to remove the whitespace within the string, it's the function to use). Just add a 'FROM' clause within the TRIM, listing all of the characters that might be present as an expression before 'FROM', like...

```
TRIM(' $' + char(9) + char(10) + char(13) FROM ProductAlternateKey)
```

would remove leading and trailing spaces, dollar signs, tabs, returns and linefeeds from the string. You can, of course, assign the expression to a variable and reference it as needed in your code to make it more readable and maintainable...

```
TRIM(@whitespace FROM ProductAlternateKey)
```

Answer (score -3):

**Remove new line characters with SQL column data**

```
Update a set  a.CityName=Rtrim(Ltrim(REPLACE(REPLACE(a.CityName,CHAR(10),' '),CHAR(13),' ')))
,a.postalZone=Rtrim(Ltrim(REPLACE(REPLACE(a.postalZone,CHAR(10),' '),CHAR(13),' ')))  
From tAddress a 
inner Join  tEmployees p  on a.AddressId =p.addressId 
Where p.MigratedID is not null and p.AddressId is not null AND
(REPLACE(REPLACE(a.postalZone,CHAR(10),'Y'),CHAR(13),'X') Like 'Y%' OR REPLACE(REPLACE(a.CityName,CHAR(10),'Y'),CHAR(13),'X') Like 'Y%')
```