# Data is splitting into multiple rows while copying from sql server 2012 to excel sheet

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2012

SQl Query :

```
select REPLACE(REPLACE(cast(description as nvarchar(max)), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), '')[description] From EuroRawData where message like '%Dewan Sabuj%'
```

`Description` column is ntext. Without using replace the result was this :

```
অনেক সময় প্রিয়জনের
মোবাইলে টাকা দেয়ার প্রয়োজন
হয়। কিন্তু তখন যদি দেখেন
ফ্লেক্সিলোড দেওয়া যাচ্ছে
না – তাহলে তো সমস্যা । তবে এখন
আপনি আপনার স্ক্র্যাচ কার্ড দিয়েই
বন্ধুর মোবাইলে রিচার্জ করে দিতে
পারবেন । আপনাকে যা করতে হবেঃ-
▄► জিপির গ্রাহকদের জন্য :
ডায়াল করুন *555*১৬ ডিজিটের
Card Number*বন্ধুর মোবাইল
নাম্বার#
.
.
▄► Airtel গ্রাহকদের জন্য :
ডায়াল করুন *801*বন্ধুর মোবাইল
নাম্বার* Card Number#
.
.
▄► রবি গ্রাহকদের জন্যঃ ডায়াল
*111*কার্ডের গোপন নাম্বার*
বন্ধুর নাম্বার#
[অনেক কষ্ট করে আপনাদের জন্য
টিপসগুলো লিখি । টিপস গুলো পড়ে
উপকৃত হলে লাইক কমেন্ট করবেন
। লাইক কমেন্ট পাইলে নতুন নতুন
টিপস লিখতে উৎসাহ পাই ।]
```

After using replace result is :

```
অনেক সময় প্রিয়জনেরমোবাইলে টাকা দেয়ার প্রয়োজনহয়। কিন্তু তখন যদি দেখেনফ্লেক্সিলোড দেওয়া যাচ্ছেনা – তাহলে তো সমস্যা । তবে এখনআপনি আপনার স্ক্র্যাচ কার্ড দিয়েইবন্ধুর মোবাইলে রিচার্জ করে দিতেপারবেন । আপনাকে যা করতে হবেঃ-▄► জিপির গ্রাহকদের জন্য :ডায়াল করুন *555*১৬ ডিজিটেরCard Number*বন্ধুর মোবাইলনাম্বার#..▄► Airtel গ্রাহকদের জন্য :ডায়াল করুন *801*বন্ধুর মোবাইলনাম্বার* Card Number#..▄► রবি গ্রাহকদের জন্যঃ ডায়াল*111*কার্ডের গোপন নাম্বার*বন্ধুর নাম্বার#[অনেক কষ্ট করে আপনাদের জন্যটিপসগুলো লিখি । টিপস গুলো পড়েউপকৃত হলে লাইক কমেন্ট করবেন
। লাইক কমেন্ট পাইলে নতুন নতুনটিপস লিখতে উৎসাহ পাই ।]
```

The problem is - Even after using `replace` it is breaking into two lines while pasting in excel or if u simply it paste any where.

All i want is the data should be displayed in one line while pasting to excel or any where. Please help!

Comment: I tried giving a quick look at your text and it looks like there's another 'brake' symbol which seems to be not recognized by REPLACE. I've pasted it into Word and it looks like this http://prntscr.com/6hw930. However I didn't find a way to find its ascii code. Not a solution, but maybe something into right direction...

Comment: I'm also not able to find any solution for that. There are 10-20 records like that in the table causing mismatch in excel export

Comment: take an advanced text editor like Notepad++ and look at the data with option "display nonprintable characters" (hex mode will help too), you'll sure find another breaking character

Comment: This looks to be an Arabic charset; ISO 8859-6