# Remove spaces from string and select using that string in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I am trying to select some of the records using a string which has space so I trim and use but something is wrong please correct me where something is missed by me.

```
SELECT * FROM projects where str_id=ltrim(rtrim('   artf130 ')) --- No rows selected
SELECT * FROM projects where str_id='artf130' -- one row selected
```

**Update:** I copied the first line from google spread sheet.

Comment: Hello! Maybe take a look in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211346/how-to-remove-white-space-characters-from-a-string-in-sql-server   And maybe give the answer a vote up.

Comment: @Cataklysim thanks and given.

Comment: @sunleo  "so I trim and use but something is wrong please correct me"  what is that 'something'?  show us some sample data.

Comment: When I copied from google spread sheet some in-visible characters are there and, ltrim and rtrim could not remove them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe that was my bad. People keep helping. 
I think my comment was enough, cause I linked to a very similar problem, which got a answer. So here for everyone:

[You can see the answer to that question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211346/how-to-remove-white-space-characters-from-a-string-in-sql-server)