# Removing whitespace in MSSQL and trailing spaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I'm trying to remove whitespace and trailing white space from right and left side of my string in DB.

Note how the current results looklike:

[image]

Note the string named:

```
*excellent-purchase*
```

When I fetch it in my C# application like this:

```
ctx.Users.ToList();
```

The output for this string that I get is:

```
\t*excellent-purchase*
```

I need to remove this "\t" sign from my C# application either on DB level or inside the C# application.

The way I've tried it is like doing it is like this:

```
UPDATE
    TableName
SET
    ColumnName = LTRIM(RTRIM(ColumnName))
```

But I still get this \t sign in my C# app...

How can I fix this?

Edit:

guys I still have a weird characther like this:

```
"nl_holyland*555*
```

And in the C# App it looks like:

```
\"nl_holyland*555*
```

Theres an extra \ with this solution like

Comment: \t isn't whitespace it's a tab. use `Replace(ColumnName, char(9), '')` in addition. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906949/how-eliminate-the-tab-space-in-the-column-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: You could also use [TrimStart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If there are other characters, you could look at [RegEx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046740/how-can-i-validate-a-string-to-only-allow-alphanumeric-characters-in-it)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211346/how-to-remove-white-space-characters-from-a-string-in-sql-server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove white space characters from a string in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211346/how-to-remove-white-space-characters-from-a-string-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

You can try it:

string value=  Regex.Replace(value, @"\t|\n|\r", "");

Comment: Yes, it case use Replace(Replace(column,char(9),''), char(13),'') in SQL Server.

Comment: Junior, I still get a \ sign left with this solution

Comment: Probably you are with caracter " in register. You can try replace Replace(Replace(column,char(9),''), char(34),'').

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the following:

```
UPDATE
    TableName
SET
    ColumnName = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(ColumnName,char(9),'')))
```

Comment: I still have a weird characther like this:

    "nl_holyland*555*

And in the C# App it looks like:

    \"nl_holyland*555*

Theres an extra \ with this solution like

Comment: This is most certainly because " is a reserved character and has to be escaped, which is done via adding \ to the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Replace also:

```
UPDATE
    TableName
SET
    ColumnName =  REPLACE(ColumnName, ' ', '')
```