# Find a "tabulator" space in a text field on SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have several tex fields (varchar, nvarchar, ....) in a SQL Server 2012.

These fields are updated by the "users" pasting from different sources. And sometime, they paste a text that includes a "tabulator" space.

Obviously I can find spaces using:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE field LIKE '%   %' /*3 spaces*/
OR field LIKE '%    %' /*4 spaces*/
OR field LIKE '%     %' /*5 spaces*/
OR field LIKE '%      %' /*6 spaces*/
```

But is there any specific way to find out "tabulator" spaces inside a text field?

Regards!

Comment: An answer may already exist here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906949/how-eliminate-the-tab-space-in-the-column-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for using "tabulator" instead of "tab" :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find them you can use `charindex()` with `char(9)`.

```
select * 
from t
where charindex(char(9),col)>0;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/OOX36348

Comment: Thanks at all. I have tested it, and works correctly. I think that is the easiest way to find out where is a tab space in a column. (At least to find it; not modify). Very thanks at all!

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you want to get rid of those extra spaces, here is a little technique Gordon demonstrated several weeks ago.  **It will handle ANY NUMBER of repeating spaces.**

```
Declare @YourTable table (col varchar(100))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('Some    text    with extra spaces')

Select *
      ,Trimmed = replace(replace(replace(col,' ','><'),'<>',''),'><',' ')
 From  @YourTable
```

Returns

```
col                                 Trimmed
Some    text    with extra spaces   Some text with extra spaces
```

> ***EDIT - To Update***

```
Update YourTable
   set col = replace(replace(replace(col,' ','><'),'<>',''),'><',' ')
 Where col like '%  %'
```

No need to search for 3+ spaces, searching for double spaces will do the trick

Comment: Exactly. My idea is to remove this spaces. At least, find them. Thanks!

Comment: @jorge_vicente to find then where col like '%  %'   two spaces no need to 3,4,5